# How to collect a map after group by in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this:

```
|  id  |  time  |  cat  |
-------------------------
   1       t1       a
   1       t2       b
   2       t3       b
   2       t4       c
   2       t5       b
   3       t6       a
   3       t7       a
   3       t8       a
```

Now, I want to group them by "id" and aggregate them into a Map like this:

```
|   id  |       cat       |
---------------------------
|   1   |  a -> 1, b -> 1 |
|   2   |  b -> 2, c -> 1 |
|   3   |  a -> 3         |
```

I guess we can use pyspark sql function's ***collect_list*** to collect them as list, and then I could apply some UDF function to turn the list into dict. But is there any other (shorter or more efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this function from [`pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries)
if we consider your dataframe is df you should do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.groupby("id", "cat").count()
df2 = df1.groupby("id")\
         .agg(F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list(F.struct("cat","count"))).alias("cat"))
```

Answer (score 1):

similar to yasi's answer

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = df.groupby("id", "cat").count()
df2 = df1.groupby("id")\
         .agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list("cat"),F.collect_list("count"))).alias("cat"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it.

Code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'t1','a'),(1,'t2','b'),(2,'t3','b'),(2,'t4','c'),(2,'t5','b'),\
(3,'t6','a'),(3,'t7','a'),(3,'t8','a')],\
('id','time','cat'))

(df.groupBy(['id', 'cat'])
   .agg(F.count(F.col('cat')).cast(StringType()).alias('counted'))
   .select(['id', F.concat_ws('->', F.col('cat'), F.col('counted')).alias('arrowed')])
   .groupBy('id')
   .agg(F.collect_list('arrowed'))
   .show()
)
```

Output

```
+-------+---------------------+
|     id|collect_list(arrowed)|
+-------+---------------------+
|   1   |    [a -> 1, b -> 1] |
|   3   |            [a -> 3] |
|   2   |    [b -> 2, c -> 1] |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Edit

```
(df.groupBy(['id', 'cat'])
   .count()
   .select(['id',F.create_map('cat', 'count').alias('map')])
   .groupBy('id')
   .agg(F.collect_list('map').alias('cat'))
   .show()
)

#+---+--------------------+
#| id|                 cat|
#+---+--------------------+
#|  1|[[a -> 1], [b -> 1]]|
#|  3|          [[a -> 3]]|
#|  2|[[b -> 2], [c -> 1]]|
#+---+--------------------+
```

Comment: You simply added the string `->` in between the keys and the values. That is not at all what the question is asking.

Comment: @pault Ops, I read that question too quickly. Noted and edited.

Comment: This is better, but it's still not the right output. You have an array of maps, rather than one `MapType`